# How to connect to AD (on-prem) with Asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, active-directory

I need to authenticate to my Active Directory (on-prem) using ASP.Net Core. I'vre looked into LDAP, DirectoryEntery and other libraries, but I need some advise on what's the best approach to make said connection. Does anyone know how I should start and what's the best library to do this.

(Note: I'm using ASP.Net Core version 3.1)

Comment: The only one I've got to work with .NET Core 3.1 was Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard

Comment: Thank you! Do you know any github project or tutorial that will help me understand it mode?